# Xcode error: Failed to set () user defined inspected property: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, debugging

EDIT

```
//  EnterValueScreen.swift
//  myfirstapp

import UIKit

class EnterValueScreen: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

        // outlet fields


    @IBOutlet weak var enterValue: UITextField!
    var val: Double!
    var convertedVal: Double!
    var weightBool: Bool = true
    var weightName: String!

    @IBOutlet weak var outputLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var segmentControl: UISegmentedControl!
    //outputField.text = ans

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        enterValue.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    @IBAction func enterValueTouch(_ sender: UITextField) {
    }


    @IBAction func indexedWeight(_ sender: Any) {
        switch segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            weightBool = true
        case 1:
            weightBool = false
        default:
            weightBool = true
        }
    }
    //
    func convertEquations(_ weight: Bool, insertValueFromTextField value: Double) -> Double {

        if weight == true {
            print("we doin Kgs")
            convertedVal = 2.20462 * value
            weightName = "Pounds"


        } else {
            print("we doin lbs")
            convertedVal = value / 2.20462
            weightName = "Kilos"
        }

        return convertedVal.rounded(toPlaced: 1)
    }

    @IBAction func convertButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //execute function converter

        val = Double(enterValue.text ?? "0")

        convertEquations(weightBool, insertValueFromTextField: val)

        outputLabel.text = String(convertedVal) + " \(weightName!)"
    }
}


extension Double {
    func rounded(toPlaced places:Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}
```

This is the error I get given:

2019-05-06 11:45:01.601637+0100 myfirstapp[3695:385041] Failed to set () user defined inspected property on (myfirstapp.EnterValueScreen): [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key .
2019-05-06 11:45:04.016105+0100 myfirstapp[3695:385041] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /Users/james/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/976DE92D-F68B-4608-9EC5-E68B0EB658A6/data/Containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2019-05-06 11:45:04.016549+0100 myfirstapp[3695:385041] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings.
2019-05-06 11:45:04.071007+0100 myfirstapp[3695:385041] Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitTruffle-NumberPad; using 20615_PortraitTruffle_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default

Comment: Please repost the error. Copy and paste it exactly. There should not be all of those `//` and you left off the most important part of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `super.viewDidLoad();` in your `override func viewDidLoad()` method.

like

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

If it did not work then try to delete and reconnect connection of viewController from storyboard.